# Can we copy nested JS Object's value by reference?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose i have this nested object say:

```
let x = {
          'key1': {
                    'key1_1':'value 1.1',
                    'key1_2': 'value 1.2'
                    'key1_3': 'value 1.3'
                   }
         }
```

And I'm copying one of the key as

```
  let y = x.key1;
```

And now I'm changing `key1` value as

```
  let z =  {
             'key1': {
                    'key1_1':'new value 1.1',
                    'key1_2': ' new value 1.2'
                    'key1_3': ' new value 1.3'
              }
            }

    x.key1 = z.key1
```

Now if I do

```
console.log(y.key1_1) //output: value 1.1    desired output: new value 1.1
```

I want the output to be latest value which is `new value 1.1`
Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Not possible to do this. All variables are *values*. For an object, that value is its reference. However, so, if you do `a = {}; b = a` then both point at the same object. However, `a = {foo: bar}` will change `a` to point to a *different* object, it will not modify what `b` points to.

Comment: Are you looking for `Object.assign(x.key1, z.key1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `x.key1 = z.key1;` then it will create new reference for `x.key1` so `y.key1` will have different `reference` than `x.key1`.

To get result as per your expectation you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method like `Object.assign(x.key1, z.key1);`.

You can check it below.

```js
let x = {
  'key1': {
    'key1_1': 'value 1.1',
    'key1_2': 'value 1.2',
    'key1_3': 'value 1.3'
  }
}
let y = x.key1;

let z = {
  'key1': {
    'key1_1': 'new value 1.1',
    'key1_2': ' new value 1.2',
    'key1_3': ' new value 1.3'
  }
}

Object.assign(x.key1, z.key1);

console.log(y.key1_1)
```

Comment: Yes,I have'nt thought of using ```Object.assign``` in that way,This is what I was looking for.